# Doxygen: Go to the source code of this file

Tags: c, doxygen

I want to show this  option in my html document, I mean: "Go to the source code of this file."
In watchdog.h it appears but in watchdog.c it doesnt appear and I can't find any reason for this.

In config file I have this:

```
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
```

So in theory it should appear. Maybe i can use a special command from doxygen to call the filecode. Any idea?

Also I tried using HTML code, but it suggest me to download the code instead of displaying it.

```
*       <A HREF=../watchdog.c><B> Go to the source code </B></A>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the SOURCE_BROWSER in the config file? or at the \snippet possibilities?

Comment: Yes. I did, but it sends me to the document of watchdog.c not to the source code.

Comment: By the way, i found an HTML code to open the file: 
    <a href="../watchdog.c" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ><b>Go to the source code</b></a>, but it shows me the code as txt, not as a file seen by Doxygen.

Comment: As I understand you want to go to the source code doxygen used and e.g. edit it. With the .h this is not the case either (as far as I known). It would also mean that you cannot move doxygen to another place without also copying the source files. The file shown by doxygen is  copy with syntax, partial, highlighting of the code. It is possible to strip comments (see STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS).

Comment: More or less, but I don't want to edit it, I simply want to see the code ass doxygen sees it, with lines on the left and if I click on a function it will take me to the description of the function. And yes, this way I will have to copy my html document together with my source files.

Comment: As far as I can see what you want is exactly what the SOURCE_BROWSER does. You write "I simply want to see the code as doxygen sees it", I don't see the difference between the original code and the version from the SOURCE_BROWSER, maybe you can give a small example (input file and SOURCE_BROWSER output, or a small project showing it) to clarify.

Comment: Dont worry I already solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help, with your advices I found what was doing wrong. In the end I changed the config file and now it links to the source code. And yes. SOURCE_BROWSER did great. 
For the record my mistake was with the config file itself, everytime I changed something in the config file I used doxygen -u and thought that it updated the general configfile but i always ran "doxygen watchdog.c", so in the end I never used my configfile. Now I use Doxygenfile as a make file and run it like: "doxygen Doxyfile" and it does exactly what i want.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem, I also understand now why I didn't understand your problems.